# android version or pixels problem in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout

I am a beginner in flutter app development(~1 month). I am getting an error in the code in which the same code runs fine in pixel 2XL (size:- 5.99, API -: 29), but when I run the same code in galaxy Nexus(size-: 4.65, API-: 23) it doesn't run the same.[image] This is a simple page in pixel 2XL
[image]
this is the same page in the galaxy nexus

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _page1State createState() => _page1State();
}

class _page1State extends State<page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  width: 200,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/oreo.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "mytime is an initiative",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              letterSpacing: 2.5,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "by XYZ Texhnologies",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              letterSpacing: 2.5,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "to provide quality",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              letterSpacing: 2.5,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "programming education to people",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              letterSpacing: 2.5,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                      
                          SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the code for the page.

I have no idea why this is happening. can anyone help me with this?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Your text is too big on pixel 2XL. Try making your text fontSize reponsive on mobile size/screen.

Comment: but when I make font-size small it works fine in the galaxy but then in pixel 2, it moves to the left side!!

Comment: try to wrap your parent widget column with expanded widget Row > Expanded > Column or add ```mainAxisAlignment``` on your Row, Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            ),.. if its not it, try crossAlignment in Column

Answer (score 0):

The yellow, black strip means that you are "overflowing".
Overflowing means that the element is to big for it's container.

In your particular case the text font and spacing is too big and when changing phone since **you didn't set it dynamically to adapt to different screen sizes** it goes beyond the borders.

You can either reduce the font size or set it dynamically.

If you are new to Flutter i recommend this course to get such basics.

--> https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-flutter-dart-to-build-ios-android-apps/

I took it myself and it's very well explained and goes from basics topics like this one to difficult ones.

Hope this will help you more then just answering the question.